# Generated JAR in Eclipse 64Bits not working

Tags: eclipse, jar, 64-bit

I have a project which is used as a JAR library in another EAR. When I deploy the EAR and run the web application, I get an error that a third party library cannot find the packages in the jar.

However, if I extract the JAR contents and then create again the JAR, it works fine. So apparently, there is a problem with Eclipse 64Bits when generating the JAR.

Also I have tried to generate the JAR in another pc with Eclipse 32Bits, and also it works fine.

Any idea why is this happening?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it is to mark the option "Add directory entries" in export dialog.